# Can a single parameter value have multiple possible values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to create a specific value in a SSRS parameter that is composed of multiple possible values.

Because in the back-end, each of these Label-value pairs can have multpile possible values.

I wanted to see if i could use a temp -table with those values hard-coded, but not sure how

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and I would strongly suggest looking into the following two alternatives to the solution you're aiming for:

- If those values (30, 35, 36, and 40) have a shared meaning, consider normalizing them in a table in your database, and having the value for `SecurityDrops` correspond to that group of values (e.g. through the foreign key).
- Use a magic value such as "-1" and have the query define an exception for that situation.
- Use a magic value such as "-1" for `SecurityDrops`, and if it is selected have another parameter pop up for `SecurityDropValues` that is MultiValued and allows the user to input 30, 35, 26, and 40.

If you insist on the direction you suggest in the question, the "solution" would be to make the parameter of type text, and allow the user to input comma-seperated values. You'll have to parse the input for the parameter in the SQL then though, which isn't pretty.

Comment: Hi Jeroen - just curious, I was a little puzzled at the second tip there - " a magic value such as "-1" and have the query define an exception for that situation."

Comment: Create a possible value "-1" with a label "Multiple Security Drops", and if it is selected: show a new multi-valued parameter to allow the user to choose those Drops.